# How to detect if user inputs a letter inside a menu

Tags: c, c99

I'm making a menu for a game, and when I test the program and enter a character or a string, the program will run the default value for what seems like forever,

I have tried to use a strcmp(x,y) function, however that doesn't seem to work with me.

```
int main(void) {
    int run = 1;
    int choice;
    do
    {
        printf("options: \n1. foo \n2.Bar \n");
        scanf("%d", &choice")
        switch (choice) {
        case 1: printf("hello world \n");
            break;
        case 2: printf("Hello World \n");
            break;
        default: printf("enter a valid option");
            break;
        }
        } while (run == 1);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: After you print the question, you must get the input. Use `scanf("%d", &choice)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in a remark you never set *choice* so its value is undefined and its usage an undefined behavior

for instance replace

> ```
>         printf("options: \n1. foo \n2.Bar \n");
> ```

by

```
    printf("options: \n1. foo \n2.Bar \n");
    if (scanf("%d", &choice) != 1) {
      /* not an integer, byppass all up to the newline */
      int c;

      while ((c = getchar()) != '\n') {
        if (c == EOF) {
          fprintf(stderr, "EOF");
          return -1;
        }
      }
      choice = -1;
    }
```

or more simple getting a character rather than an *int* :

```
    char choice;
    ...
    printf("options: \n1. foo \n2.Bar \n");
    if (scanf(" %c", &choice) != 1) {
      fprintf(stderr, "EOF");
      return -1;
    }
    ...
    case '1':
    ...
    case '2':
    ...
```

notice the space before `%c` to bypass the spaces and newlines, in that case of course replace `case 1` by `case '1'` and `case 2` by `case '2'`

**Always** check the result of *scanf* if you just do `scanf("%d", &choice);` and the user do not enter a number your program will loop without ending asking for the choice and indicating the error, no more input will be get because the non number is *not* bypassed so *scanf* will get it all the time.

Note also

- both the choices 1 and 2 do `printf("hello world \n")`
- *run* is never modified so `do ... while (run == 1);` cannot end, perhaps you wanted to set *run* to 0 (I mean a value != 1) for the cases 1 and 2 ?

---

Example :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int run;
  char choice;

  do
  {
    run = 0;
    puts("options:\n 1. foo \n 2. Bar");
    if (scanf(" %c", &choice) != 1) {
      fprintf(stderr, "EOF");
      return -1;
    }

    switch (choice) {
    case '1': 
      printf("hello foo\n");
      break;
    case 2:
      printf("Hello bar \n");
      break;
    default:
      run = 1;
      puts("enter a valid option");
      break;
    }
  } while (run == 1);

  printf("all done with choice %c\n", choice);
  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wall -Wextra c.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
options:
 1. foo 
 2. Bar
a
enter a valid option
options:
 1. foo 
 2. Bar
33
enter a valid option
options:
 1. foo 
 2. Bar
enter a valid option
options:
 1. foo 
 2. Bar
1
hello foo
all done with choice 1
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Comment: Added a scanf function

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a scanf statement after printing "Options :..."

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int run = 1;
    int choice;

    do{
        printf("options: \n1. foo \n2.Bar \n");
        scanf("%d", &choice);


        switch (choice) {
            case 1: 
                printf("hello world \n");
                break;
            case 2: 
                printf("Hello World \n");
                break;
            default: 
                printf("enter a valid option\n");
                break;
        }


    }while (run == 1);

    return 0;
}
```

If you need to check if the entered value is a digit you can use the `isdigit()` function.

Comment: you confuse 1 and 2 with '1' and '2', and if you want to enter a digit better to do `scanf(" %c", &choice)` rather than a _scanf_ with `%d`

Comment: yeah but the question is with integers, so I answered with %d

Comment: Please never propose a solution getting an integer with _scanf_ without checking the return value, just run your program and enter something else than a number ...